# Why do we use absolute value to find the cosine series?

Tags: c

Why do we take the absolute value of term to find the cos series when will the term even be less than 0.0001 please explain if possible with example?

```
X = (22.0/7.0) * (Theta/180.0);    
CosX = 1.0;
Term = 1.0;
i = 1;

while(fabs(Term)>=0.0001){

    Term = (-1) * Term * X*X/((2*i-1)*2*i);
    CosX = CosX + Term;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The sign of the terms alternate: the Taylor series of cosine is

```
 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! + ...
// ^        ^        ^
```

Then, the first non-trivial term for |x| > 0 is negative and clearly < 0.0001.

Another way to handle this is to unroll twice using only positive terms.

```
do {
    Term = Term * X*X/((2*i-1)*2*i);
    CosX = CosX - Term;
    i++;
    Term = Term * X*X/((2*i-1)*2*i);
    CosX = CosX + Term;
    i++;
} while (Term > 0.0001);
```

Comment: Anyway this approach is premature optimization on arm64, which has an instruction for absolute value comparison. One more way to handle this is `CosX += sign * Term; sign = -sign;` which also works nicely on ARM -- since it has the _fused multiply accumulate_ instruction.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have to use `fabs` in the `while` loop

We can check both conditions (negative && positive) instead:

```
while( wTerm >= 0.0001 || wTerm <= -0.0001){
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the loop condition is to continue approximation until the last change is very small, indicating being close to the precise value. Of course such a condition, one way or another, is needed, because the correct value is unknown and because arriving at it (even if known) would be taking inefficient time.

However "small" for a change, a delta, is the kind of small where -10 is larger than +2. I.e. if the last change was by a big but negative step, the loop should continue. Only when the change does not move a lot anymore in either direction (positive or negative) a reasonable approximation can be assumed.

Wether that is done via taking the absolute value of the change for comparison, or do two checks (one against a small positive change and one against a large negative one - where the largest one is of course very close to 0) does not matter.